# How could I replace Alt + Tab with something else on 12.04 with Gnome 3?

Tags: shortcuts

I use Citrix Receiver to access my desktop at my firm.
Unfortunately both computers have the Alt + Tab set as application switcher shortcut.
As a consequence, when I am using the remote desktop in full screen, hitting Alt + Tab navigates me out of the remote PC.

As a workaround I would like to replace the Alt + Tap with something like Super + Tab on the Ubuntu/Gnome3 host.
However changing the shortcut in the Keyboard/Navigation/Switch Applications setting has no affect.

Could you please advise if there is any way I could still change this setting?

Best regards,
Marton